# Simulate input in own application without focus?

Tags: c++, input, focus, simulate, minimized

I was wondering if it is possible to simulate input in your own application without the window being focused or the window minimized, kind of like with PostMessage or SendMessage but without those APIs specifically? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you want to use PostMessage or SendMessage? Any why do you need to simulate input to your own code rather than trigger the actions directly? Due to hosting controls you don't have the source to or something else?

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with global hooks.
so basically windows is sending messages to the application which is focused, but apps with global hooks will get all the input events for which they registered for inputs.